# Android, cannot get method setOnLongClickListener to work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to detect a long click and get a:

> The method 'setOnLongClickListener' in type view is not applicable for the argument 'new OnLongClickListener()'

the code looks like:

```
t.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //Offer additional options when the view is held.
            MakeRingtune( strLastSound);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: what kind of variable is t?

Comment: On Which view you are trying to apply onLongClickListener?

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple inner class named `OnLongClickListener` in the android API : `View.OnLongClickListener` and `AdapterView.OnLongClickListener`.

So check your import statments and ensure that you use the correct one.